# Facebook Post Delete

Tags: android, facebook

Hello I Developed on app that connect with Facebook and get all post of that user and if i search with particular words search and that written post will display in list view but Facebook provide me that delete post API??

I search Facebook developer account but its tell only if your created application posted post that can be delete otherwise don't delete ? its true or not?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/post/

i try above link but not delete post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An app can delete any post it published, or a page-management app can delete a Post published to a Page that the app manages.

The docs are quite clear. You can only delete posts made by that app.